# C# drawimages multiple images into picturebox without tiling

Tags: c#, picturebox, drawimage

I am trying to draw multiple (20 small images or more) into a single picture box using points however when I do this it copies the top line on each line of the picture box.
I have searched everywhere and tried many times to get this right but I cant figure it out can anyone help point me in the right direction?

what i'm trying to accomplish is:

1. image1  image2   image3   image4   image1
2. image2  image4   image1   image3   image3
3. image4  image7   image2   image1   image6
4. image3  image7   image3   image7   image6

however what i get is:

1. image1  image2   image3   image4   image1
2. image1  image2   image3   image4   image1
3. image1  image2   image3   image4   image1
4. image1  image2   image3   image4   image1

(without the numbers of course)
here is the code I am using

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image[] Files = new Image[7]; 
    Bitmap a = new Bitmap(@"C:\icons\icon1.png");
    Files[0] = new Bitmap(a, 80, 80);
    image1 = Files[0];
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\icons\icon2.png");
    Files[1] = new Bitmap(b, 80, 80);
    image2 = Files[1];
    Bitmap c = new Bitmap(@"C:\icons\icon3.png");
    Files[2] = new Bitmap(c, 80, 80);
    image3 = Files[2];
    Bitmap d = new Bitmap(@"C:\icons\icon4.png");
    Files[3] = new Bitmap(d, 80, 80);
    image4 = Files[3];
    Bitmap h = new Bitmap(@"C:\icons\icon5.png");
    Files[4] = new Bitmap(h, 80, 80);
    image5 = Files[4];
    Bitmap f = new Bitmap(@"C:\icons\icon6.png");
    Files[5] = new Bitmap(f, 80, 80);
    image6 = Files[5];
    Bitmap g = new Bitmap(@"C:\icons\icon7.png");
    Files[6] = new Bitmap(g, 80, 80);
    image7 = Files[6];

    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = CombineBitmap(Files);
}

public static System.Drawing.Bitmap CombineBitmap(Image[] files)
    {
        List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> images = new List<System.Drawing.Bitmap>();
        System.Drawing.Bitmap finalImage = null;

        try
        {
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;

            foreach (Image image in files)
            {
                System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(image);

                width += bitmap.Width;
                height = bitmap.Height > height ? bitmap.Height : height;

                images.Add(bitmap);
            }

            finalImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);

            using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(finalImage))
            {
                g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Gray); // Change this to whatever you want the background color to be, you may set this to Color.Transparent as well

                int offset = 15;
                Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
                Point p2 = new Point(80, 0);
                Point p3 = new Point(160, 0);
                Point p4 = new Point(240, 0);
                Point p5 = new Point(320, 0);

                Point p6 = new Point(0, 80);
                Point p7 = new Point(80, 80);
                Point p8 = new Point(160, 80);
                Point p9 = new Point(240, 80);
                Point p10 = new Point(320, 80);

                Point p11 = new Point(0, 160);
                Point p12 = new Point(80, 160);
                Point p13 = new Point(160, 160);
                Point p14 = new Point(240, 160);
                Point p15 = new Point(320, 160);

                Point p16 = new Point(0, 240);
                Point p17 = new Point(80, 240);
                Point p18 = new Point(160, 240);
                Point p19 = new Point(240, 240);
                Point p20 = new Point(320, 240);


                g.DrawImage(image1, p1);
                g.DrawImage(image2, p2);
                g.DrawImage(image3, p3);
                g.DrawImage(image4, p4);
                g.DrawImage(image1, p5);


                g.DrawImage(image2, p6);
                g.DrawImage(image4, p7);
                g.DrawImage(image1, p8);
                g.DrawImage(image3, p9);
                g.DrawImage(image3, p10);

                g.DrawImage(image4, p11);
                g.DrawImage(image7, p12);
                g.DrawImage(image2, p13);
                g.DrawImage(image1, p14);
                g.DrawImage(image6, p15);

                g.DrawImage(image3, p16);
                g.DrawImage(image7, p17);
                g.DrawImage(image3, p18);
                g.DrawImage(image7, p19);
                g.DrawImage(image6, p20);

               }

            return finalImage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (finalImage != null)
                finalImage.Dispose();

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {

            foreach (System.Drawing.Bitmap image in images)
            {
                image.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your `finalImage` bitmap is too small, and is only allowing a single row of images.  The PictureBox control is then tiling the single row of images to give you the image you're seeing.

You are drawing the images in blocks 80 pixels wide by 80 pixels high.  The bitmap therefore should be wide enough to hold `80 * numColumns` pixels, and tall enough to hold `80 * numRows` pixels.

Since you have 5 columns and 4 rows, use this:

```
finalImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(400, 320);
```

Comment: Oh wow cant believe i over looked that. thanks that was quick!

Comment: Sometimes we can't see the forest for the trees :)